# Angular.js: templates and handling data between views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to grasp the main principles related to the next issues:

- Templates
- Data Handling
- $resource vs $http

As i see it i'd like to implement few views in my app which share few html templates and also share some data. for simplifying my issue i'll describe a scenario which is almost equivalent.
[image]

as u can see there are 2 views (though there will be more!) who use 3 html markups while one of them is shared in both views (GeneralInfo). Also, both views share data which will be normally created while using one of the view's controller.

1. What principle of angular should be used to make sure that while changing the route i could keep my data shared between the views.

   - Should i use app.value('myVal', ..) which is Global variable?
   - Should i pass it like a service to all of my controllers?
2. More technically, how should i implement same html in both views? could u example that?

   - How should a view with it's markup contain 2 templates and how and when it is rendered?
3. what's the difference between $resource and $http and when each shouold be used?

Comment: 1. Depends on the type of the data you are trying to save. If it's more like a string, a constant|value should be fine, if it's more like object with functions on it, well a service is needed here. You could write a closure that will hold properties like getUser(), isLoggedIn() and so on. 2. You could even narrow down to 1 view. save the generalInfo on the scope, and the sky is the limit. you could even us ng-switch here. 3. $resource is meant for REST APIS, it's easier to control, since you are sending different requests on same resource. $http is creating a regular AJAX requests.helped.

Comment: 1. So i'm guessing it's either a service or a global variable (which less fit in here), i thought there is another way to do that. regarding 2: i wanted to know technically how should i load these html templates (by directives?). Also, i didn't get your point bout narrowing it down to a single view, generalInfo is an html, how is it related to a scope ?

Comment: 1. exactly, registering a service|factory|provider means registering a singelton that will be available anywhere you choose on the app. you have to declare a dependency. 2. there is a slight misunderstanding here by my fault. Does login form and general info in the same page or different pages? I'm kinda confused now.

Comment: 1-great explanation. 2-Yes it's on the same page, as far as im concerned i would like to do something like: <body><!--loginform.html here--><br/><!--generalinfo.html here--></body> hope it simplify my need.

Comment: 1.Thanks! 2. Alright, then I would do something like this: First set two different views. Log in and Not logged in. You need to use $route in order to use ng-view. Second set 3 different HTML fragments, loginform.html, generalinfo.html, loggedinuser.html. From here you have two choices: ONE: when you set the ng-view, you bind the template accordingly (login.html for login and so on.) and beneath that you can simply ng-include generalinfo.html. TWO: set the ng-view simply to two different templates and beneath them at the index.html add the generalinfo.html. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) should use a Service to share data between controllers. technically, you could attach values on $rootScope and it would be visible across controllers, but that is considered bad form and can cause problems later (like using global variables -- can definitely have unintended side effects as the project grows if someone accidentally attaches a conflicting value).

2) not sure exactly what you're asking here. you can load a partial based on the given route/state (using ngRoute or ui-router). two different routes could use the same generalInfo.html partial, but with different data being pulled in their respective controllers. is that what you're asking?

3) $resource is an abstraction of $http -- if you're pulling data from a REST server, $resource may be a better fit, as it abstracts a little of the wiring necessary. however, if the server varies from traditional REST principles too much, or if it's not REST at all, you may just want to roll your own data access directly with $http. Of course, if it's REST and more complex, also consider restangular -- which is a more feature rich abstraction.

Comment: 1. I did try to avoid global vars so i do get your point. i assume rootScope is also global variables under this element only?
2. I checked both ngRoute and ui-router, my first impression was that ui-router gives more abilities and has more information around the web, correct me if im wrong? What i wanted to achieve is simple loading of html template in two different views, u can call it using 2 sub views under one view (should i do it with directives?)
3. I'm guessing working with WebApi would fit $resource more?

Comment: (1) anything attached to $rootScope will be available to ALL child scopes through prototypical inheritance. (2) ngRoute is the original router for AngularJS; whereas, ui-router is a more feature rich alternative, allowing things like nested routes. either one should be able to easily handle the flat example you've outlined. (3) Not familiar with WebApi, so I'm not sure. $resource gives you a little abstraction, but using $http is also simple. Not really a "right answer". I found $http to be _slightly_ simpler to learn initially and $resource _slightly_ more compact/maintainable longer term.

Comment: in answering comment (1), i'm not accounting for isolated scopes. those only inherit what you specifically name. didn't mention it for simplicity.